# Telling my parents about the guy i like but having to lie about the circumstances through which i know him

Tags: nikah, parents

I have been speaking to this guy i really like and would like to tell my parents about him soon. my uncle found out about him and i had to lie and tell him i do not speak to him anymore even though i do. this means when i tell my parents about him i have to lie and tell them i stopped talking to him for a while (2+) years. will this make my marriage be without baraqah?
i do not engage in any haram activities with this man, neither have i met him. of course i know the interaction and excessive conversation is not allowed may Allah swt help me, but can somebody please advise me on what i can do to make this situation better and also i want to know how much this can make my marriage start off without blessings since i would be lying about not talking to him

Comment: A lie creates a branches of more lies, so it's better to be regretful and truthful. Please avoid telling ( atleast in a direct tone) about your personal life and sins to strangers on internet.

Answer (score -1):

Salaam,
Firstly, the fact that you respect your parents and care about them shows that you have a good heart. Secondly, you have not done anything harm with this person, so you do not have to lie to your parents because it will just make you feel more guilty, and one lie leads to another. You also do not want to live your life with this lie in the back of your mind, so just tell them. :)
In the Qur'an it says, ""Surely Allah does not guide him aright who is a liar, ungrateful."
(Surah Zumar 39:3)
Just relax, pray, and Allah (swt) will make it easier for you to tell your parents! Hope that helps.
Best,
MuslimGap